# Launched? Launched!

Tags: discussion

I started up this SE just because it crossed my mind that it might be useful and with little hope to see it succeed. Apparently, it's now fully decorated and with a great and established community.

I just want to congratulate all of you for the great building you assembled on top of that pebble I threw.

Comment: Thank you for proposing this site!